# AssertionError encrypt in django

Tags: python, django, encryption, key, aes

so i want to encrypt text to audio mp3. but when i run the code, there's error message Exception Type:  AssertionError. and it's say there's error at

> assert len(key) == key_bytes

can someone please check what's error with the function? i want encrypt using AES 128 and 256, please help me.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter
from Crypto import Random
import binascii

key_bytes = 16
# Takes as input a 32-byte key and an arbitrary-length plaintext and returns a
# pair (iv, ciphtertext). "iv" stands for initialization vector.
def encrypt(key, testaudio):
    assert len(key) == key_bytes
    print(testaudio)
    print(key)
    # Choose a random, 16-byte IV.
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)

    # Convert the IV to a Python integer.
    iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16)

    # Create a new Counter object with IV = iv_int.
    ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int)

    # Create AES-CTR cipher.
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)

    # Encrypt and return IV and ciphertext.
    ciphertext = aes.encrypt(testaudio)
    print(iv)
    print(ciphertext)
    return (iv, ciphertext)
```

at my view, i call the function like this. where testaudio have file audio mp3.

```
enkripsi = encrypt("testing", testaudio)
            print(enkripsi)
```

Comment: You will have to show us how exactly you are calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the value of `key_bytes` as `16` but in your `encrypt` function you are using `assert` to check whether the length of `key` which is 7 when you are calling the function(length of word "testing"), either you change the value of `key_bytes` or change the value of `key` which you are passing when calling your function.

Edited:

```
import random, string
len_16_string = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=16))
print(len_16_string)
enkripsi = encrypt(len_16_string, testaudio)
print(enkripsi)
```

Comment: so how to make what key i was input, can be 16?

Comment: I have added the code, please check that.